# Error establishing a database connection error on a site that was working fine previously

Tags: errors

A site that was working fine previously is now getting an error,

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

I have dealt with this error while creating new wordpress sites(when there was something wrong with the `config` file). This time, the error occurred when the user upload a file to `public_html` folder. Can anyone suggest me **what would have gone wrong** and **how to fix it**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked your wp-config.php file? Is database name or password is changed?

Comment: Where is that located? Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked your wp-config.php file? Is database name or password is changed?

wp-config.php file is located on the root directory you installed wordpress. Open the file and you will see database password, username etc that wordpress use to connect your database. Check the username, passwords are correct.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database_name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'your_database_username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your database password');
```